# MySQL Query with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below table, and trying to retrieve the data where at-least one column (lay,blk,pri,ani) should have '1863', but the result is not as desired.

Here i am posting the Table for reference.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table; 
CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
Shot VARCHAR(4),
lay VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
lay_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
blk VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
blk_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
pri VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
pri_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
ani VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
ani_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'SH01','1863','yes','1863','yes','P4645','yes','P4557','yes'),
(2,'SH02','1863','yes','P4645','no','P4557','yes','1863','no'),
(3,'SH03','P4645','yes','P4557','yes','1863','yes','1863','yes'),
(4,'SH04','1863','no','P4645','no','P4557','yes','1863','yes'),
(5,'SH05','1863','yes','1863','yes','P4645','yes','P4557','yes'),
(6,'SH06','P4557','yes','P4645','yes','P4645','yes','P4557','yes');

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------+-------+------------+-------+------------+-------+------------+-------+------------+
| id | Shot | lay   | lay_status | blk   | blk_status | pri   | pri_status | ani   | ani_status |
+----+------+-------+------------+-------+------------+-------+------------+-------+------------+
|  1 | SH01 | 1863  | yes        | 1863  | yes        | P4645 | yes        | P4557 | yes        |
|  2 | SH02 | 1863  | yes        | P4645 | no         | P4557 | yes        | 1863  | no         |
|  3 | SH03 | P4645 | yes        | P4557 | yes        | 1863  | yes        | 1863  | yes        |
|  4 | SH04 | 1863  | no         | P4645 | no         | P4557 | yes        | 1863  | yes        |
|  5 | SH05 | 1863  | yes        | 1863  | yes        | P4645 | yes        | P4557 | yes        |
|  6 | SH06 | P4557 | yes        | P4645 | yes        | P4645 | yes        | P4557 | yes        |
+----+------+-------+------------+-------+------------+-------+------------+-------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have my created a Query and its result is as below

```
SELECT 
    x.Shot,
    IFNULL(J1.Stage,'NA') as Stage1,
    IFNULL(J1.status,'NA') as Status,
    IFNULL(J2.Stage,'NA') as Stage2,
    IFNULL(J2.status,'NA') as Status,
    IFNULL(J3.Stage,'NA') as Stage3,
    IFNULL(J3.status,'NA') as Status,
    IFNULL(J4.Stage,'NA') as Stage4,
    IFNULL(J4.status,'NA') as Status
FROM
    (SELECT 
        Shot
    FROM
        my_table) x
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
        Shot,
        lay as Artist,
        lay_status as status,
        'lay' as Stage

    FROM
        my_table where lay = '1863') J1 ON J1.Shot = x.Shot
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
        Shot,
        blk as Artist,
        blk_status as status,
        'blk' as Stage

    FROM
        my_table where blk = '1863') J2 ON J2.Shot = x.Shot
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
        Shot,
        pri as Artist,
        pri_status as status,
        'pri' as Stage

    FROM
        my_table where pri = '1863') J3 ON J3.Shot = x.Shot
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
        Shot,
        ani as Artist,
        ani_status as status,
        'ani' as Stage

    FROM
        my_table where ani = '1863') J4 ON J4.Shot = x.Shot
```

**The result of the above query is**

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Shot | Stage1 | Status | Stage2 | Status | Stage3 | Status | Stage4 | Status |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| SH01 | lay    | yes    | blk    | yes    | NA     | NA     | NA     | NA     |
| SH02 | lay    | yes    | NA     | NA     | NA     | NA     | ani    | no     |
| SH03 | NA     | NA     | NA     | NA     | pri    | yes    | ani    | yes    |
| SH04 | lay    | no     | NA     | NA     | NA     | NA     | ani    | yes    |
| SH05 | lay    | yes    | blk    | yes    | NA     | na     | NA     | NA     |
| SH06 | NA     | NA     | NA     | NA     | NA     | NA     | NA     | NA     |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

But i need to retrieve the records where at-least one among the lay,blk,pri,ani has '1863', but the above query has returned the record with SH06 where non of the fields (lay,blk,pri,ani) has '1863'

**required result is like below**

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Shot | Stage1 | Status | Stage2 | Status | Stage3 | Status | Stage4 | Status |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| SH01 | lay    | yes    | blk    | yes    | NA     | NA     | NA     | NA     |
| SH02 | lay    | yes    | NA     | NA     | NA     | NA     | ani    | no     |
| SH03 | NA     | NA     | NA     | NA     | pri    | yes    | ani    | yes    |
| SH04 | lay    | no     | NA     | NA     | NA     | NA     | ani    | yes    |
| SH05 | lay    | yes    | blk    | yes    | NA     | NA     | NA     | NA     |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, although I think your expected result for Status 3 may be wrong:

```
SELECT
  Shot,
  CASE lay WHEN 1863 THEN 'lay' ELSE 'NA' END AS 'Stage1',
  CASE WHEN lay=1863 THEN lay_status ELSE 'NA' END AS 'Status-lay',
  CASE blk WHEN 1863 THEN 'blk' ELSE 'NA' END AS 'Stage2',
  CASE WHEN blk=1863 THEN blk_status ELSE 'NA' END AS 'Status-blk',
  CASE pri WHEN 1863 THEN 'pri' ELSE 'NA' END AS 'Stage3',
  CASE WHEN pri=1863 THEN pri_status ELSE 'NA' END AS 'Status-pri',
  CASE ani WHEN 1863 THEN 'ani' ELSE 'NA' END AS 'Stage4',
  CASE WHEN ani=1863 THEN ani_status ELSE 'NA' END AS 'Status-ani'
FROM
  my_table
WHERE
  lay = 1863
OR
  blk = 1863
OR
  pri = 1863
OR
  ani = 1863
```

This gives the following results:

```
| SHOT | STAGE1 | STATUS-LAY | STAGE2 | STATUS-BLK | STAGE3 | STATUS-PRI | STAGE4 | STATUS-ANI |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SH01 |    lay |        yes |    blk |        yes |     NA |         NA |     NA |         NA |
| SH02 |    lay |        yes |     NA |         NA |     NA |         NA |    ani |         no |
| SH03 |     NA |         NA |     NA |         NA |    pri |        yes |    ani |        yes |
| SH04 |    lay |         no |     NA |         NA |     NA |         NA |    ani |        yes |
| SH05 |    lay |        yes |    blk |        yes |     NA |         NA |     NA |         NA |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef7d9/31/0

Comment: You are right there was a mistake in my SQL statement it should be `J3.Shot = x.Shot` instead i kept `J2.Shot = x.Shot`. Thx for correcting me. Your solution worked +1...